# Python Errno 2 - No such file, leading zeros

Tags: python

Here's my program:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import itertools
import os
import csv
import shutil

src = 'src';
dst = 'dst';

data = []
n = 1

while n < 233:
    charn = str(n)
    for j in range(1,9): # This will represent each plug subdirectory
        for i in range(1,30):
            if i < 10:
                chari = str(i).zfill(2)
                charj = str(j).zfill(2)
                shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
            chari = str(i)
            charj = str(j).zfill(2)
            shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
    print chari
    print charj
    print charn
    n = n + 1
```

So I'm copying folders from one directory to another (232 different folders), but some folders have leading zeros. For instance, it might look like this:

HS_BIN_I01_J01

While others look like this:

HS_BIN_I12_J08 (J never goes beyond 08, while I goes up to 29).

So naturally, I need to accommodate for these leading zeros when I write my script. Unfortunately, I get the following error when I execute it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cpfldr_232points.py", line 34, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/shutil.py", line 136, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/src/HS_BIN_I1_J01/'
```

BUT! When I go into my destination directory, the folder has been copied correctly as:

HS_BIN_I01_J01.

So it says the folder doesn't exist, but then copies it correctly anyway and immediately stops (no other folders are copied).

What's going on here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an else statement:

```
    if i < 10:
        chari = str(i).zfill(2)
        charj = str(j).zfill(2)
        shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
    chari = str(i)
    charj = str(j).zfill(2)
    shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
```

Right now, your code will perform both of the bits of code above, whether the number is less than 10 or not.  It should be:

```
if i < 10:
    chari = str(i).zfill(2)
    charj = str(j).zfill(2)
    shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
else:
    chari = str(i)
    charj = str(j).zfill(2)
    shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
```

You don't actually need the second part at all, however.  After your `if i in range(1, 30):` just do:

```
chari = str(i).zfill(2)
charj = str(j).zfill(2)
shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
```

The zfill will take care of adding leading zeroes if necessary.

Comment: Trying it now. This would blow my mind if it worked because I was getting a bunch of errors when I had an else statement attached. Looked up some Python syntax and it had no else statement.

So it worked, sort of. Instead of copying it into separate directories, it copied everything into the first directory (n = 1).

Comment: That fixed it mostly. I removed the if-then statement. Thanks for the tip on zfill. Still having all folders copied into each subdirectory, but I'll figure that one out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem.  Check to be sure you're still incrementing `n` in the right place.  Right now it's going to go through the range 1-30, then increment `n` and go through the range again.

Comment: Fixed the indexing, too. Thanks for the hint =)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the intention of your code clearer by utilising string formatting to do the zero-padding and the `product` method from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) module in the Python standard library:

```
import itertools
import shutil
import os.path

src = 'src'
dst = 'dst'
for i, j in itertools.product(range(1, 9), range(1, 30)):
    dirname = 'HS_BIN_I{0:02}_J{1:02}'.format(i, j)
    destdir = '{prefix}{n}'.format(prefix=dst, n=i*j)
    shutil.copytree(os.path.join(src, dirname),
                    os.path.join(destdir, dirname))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping a lot more than 233 times. You're iterating `n` 232 times, `j` 8 times, and `i` 29 times. 232 * 8 * 29 = 53824. So one of the things going on is that you are generating a lot more paths than you think you are.

Second, it's entirely unclear what paths you're actually generating. The code is too complex to guess with ease. Instead of:

```
shutil.copytree(src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/',dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/')
```

Consider:

```
src_path = src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/'
dst_path = dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/'
shutil.copytree(src_path, dst_path)
```

It's easier to read, and it lets you insert an all-important print statement that will *show* you what results are occurring.

```
src_path = src+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/'
dst_path = dst+charn+'/'+'HS_BIN_I'+chari+'_J'+charj+'/'
print "src_path:", src_path, "dst_path:", dst_path
shutil.copytree(src_path, dst_path)
```

That will demonstrate that you are generating paths that seem to be missing a key `"/"` separator:

```
src_path: 'srcHS_BIN_I10_J08/'  dst_path: 'dst232/HS_BIN_I10_J08/'
```

Even better, generate your path statements with higher-level formatting operations. You're doing a lot of manual conversions that the `format` method of strings does more cleanly. For example,

```
src_path = "{src}/HS_BIN_I{i:02d}_J{j:02d}/'.format(**locals())
```

Does string interpolation of values (`src`, `i`, and `j`) from the local context (roughly, the function into which you should drop this code), and does so using format specifiers like `:02d` ("two-digit integer with leading zeros, if needed").

Final code:

```
def copy_dirs(src, dst):
    """
    Copy subfolders from `src` directory into `dst` directory,
    if they are present.
    """
    for n in range(1, 233):
        for j in range(1, 9):
            for i in range(1, 30):
                src_path = "{src}/HS_BIN_I{i:02d}_J{j:02d}/".format(**locals())
                dst_path = "{dst}/{n}/HS_BIN_I{i:02d}_J{j:02d}/".format(**locals())
                # print "src_path:", src_path, "dst_path:", dst_path
                if os.path.isdir(src_path):
                    shutil.copytree(src_path, dst_path)
```

I still don't think you want to copy 50K+ directories...but maybe you do. If so, this is a cleaner, more bulletproofed way to do it.